# Openshift proxy timeout

Tags: proxy, timeout, openshift

I have an application hosted with Openshift and I need it to generate some Excel reports. The report generation process can take a long time (over 5 minutes). This causes the the client to see a 502 error and the request times out. How can and where can I configure my Openshift stack (it is a Java webapp running from Tomcat6) to increase the timeout duration?

Answer (score 0):

5 minutes is an awfully long time for a web request to run.  It would be better to have the web request schedule a background job that then notifies the user when the report is done being generated.